# What is the order of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the order of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}$?

For $\mathbb{Z}$ every non-zero element has infinite order, then $\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite order. Otherwise $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has order 2. Then what is the order of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}$? Is infinite order?

Why $\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite order?

Comment: The order of a group is its cardinality

Comment: Beware: usually $\mathbb Z_2$ stands for $2$-adic integers.

Comment: @Santiago more often, I see $\Bbb Z_2 = \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

Comment: @Santiago Actually, I think that many mathematicians would assume that $\mathbb{Z}_2$ denotes the finite group of order $2$.

Comment: Right, the order of a group has nothing to do with the order of its elements. There is a relationship between those two for finite groups, but not visa versa. There are infinite groups whose non-identity elements all have order $2$, for example. Yet the group has infinite order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is the cardinality of the group, so the order of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is 2 and the order of $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite. Therefore the order of the cartesian product is also infinite

Comment: More precisely countable infinite.